# How to delete events (data) in Elasticsearch which don't have a field tags?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone please do a favor and let me know how to delete all events generated in Elastic search which don't have a field "tags". In other words, any events should not be deleted which have a tags field available. eg. "tags": ["multiline"].

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query searching for all documents without the tags field, on the [delete by query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) API endpoint.

If you [look at the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html#query-dsl-missing-filter), you will find that you need a `missing` filter to match the documents without `tags` field defined.

Combining both elements, you will end with a query like this one :

```
DELETE /<index_name>/<type_name>/_query
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "tags"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When i run query as above it gives command not found exception. Tried writing another query but gives parsing error.   curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query' -d '{
    "query" : { 
     "term" : { "message" : "event" } 
     "filtered": { "filter": {"missing": {"field": "tags"}}}
     }    
}'

Comment: your query is malformed. Check the filtered query doc. You should have a query like {"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"term":{"message":"event"}},"filter":{"missing":{"field":"tags"}}}}}.

Comment: All events got deleted with and without tags.  This is the query:   curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.02.03/logs/' -d '{
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"term":{"message":"event"}},"filter":{"missing":{"field":"tags"}}}}}'

Comment: This query helped me deleting the required data.   curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/logstash-2015.02.04/_query?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        { "match": { "tags": "multiline" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}'